# Clarification about why we should use a SQL index when queries "expected to retrieve less 2 - 4% of rows in the table"?

Tags: sql, indexing

I'm studying some SQL and regarding queries it says :

> Create an index when the table is large and most queries are expected
>   to retrieve less than 2% to 4% of the rows in the table.

I just want to get a mental picture of what is meant by the statement. I understand that index is to make your query go much faster. Is it because the index will be focused on only that 2% to 4% of the table?

Comment: Because if there's no index, the entire table will be scanned in order to retrieve 2-4% of the data. The index allows a much smaller set of data to be scanned, closer to the 2-4% that will be retrieved.

Comment: If you want a good explanation of what an index is/does, I recommend reading this: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy - and then the rest of the book :)

Comment: @Blorgbeard - Thank you so much Blorgbeard , I will study up on that book !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databases store data in pages, data pages.  One way to make queries more efficient is by reducing the number of data pages that need to be read.

A typical database page might be 8k - 64k in size.  *If* the records are really big, there might be just one record per page.  *If* the records are quite small, there might be hundreds or even thousands on each page.

When you have an index and a condition on the column in the `where` clause, this restricts the number of rows.  The proportion is called the "selectivity" of the `where` clause.

The SQL engine has two ways of satisfying such a `where` clause.  It can read every row and compare values in each row to the condition.  This is called a "full table scan".  It can just look up the appropriate values in an index.  This is called an "index scan".

Now, when using an index for a `where` clause, what we want to do is to reduce the number of data pages being read.  This happens when we are reading, on average, less than one record per page.  This is where the 2% - 4% comes from.  Do note that if you have very large records, the number could be much larger.

However, there is a problem with this heuristic.  Indexes are used for other purposes:

- An index can be used to retrieve records in order, if the index matches the `order by` clause (and other conditions in the query are true).
- An index can be used for joining records.
- An index can be used to satisfy a query in its entirety, if the columns in the index are the only ones in the query (in this case, one says that the index "covers" the query).

So, the information you read is a heuristic.  It is a useful guideline, but it is definitely not set in stone.

Answer (score 2):

No, ff your index is on the columns in your where condition, you will not have to do a table scan. Not doing a table scan is beneficial if a smaller portion of rows is being returned.

If you are returning 100% of the rows, there is no major difference between a table scan or an index scan.

Comment: In fact, a table-scan will be faster than a (non-clustered) index scan when you are returning 100% of the rows!